# Getting Subscription and PayAsYouGo prices for Alibaba products using API/SDK

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs, alibaba-cloud-rds

My Goal is to get price (using API/SDK) for different services (like RDS,ECS, Networking etc.) provided by alibaba cloud. Official documentation just contains one example per services and also not provided details about required parameters like product codes and module codes. Please provide any references that you know about getting the prices.
Note: I don't want the official sample example links.

Comment: Maybe opening a ticket or asking the question on https://www.alibabacloud.com/forum can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the parameter details using OPEN API explorer https://api.alibabacloud.com/#/?product=Ecs&version=2014-05-26&api=DescribePrice&tab=DEMO&lang=JAVA

For example, ECS has a method named DescribePrice. Similarly I would suggest to explore OPEN API explorer for the service which you are looking for.